# Why are my assets not being loaded when using facebook web hosting for a canvas page?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, canvas

I'm using facebook web hosting for my canvas game assets and I keep getting 404 errors when they attempt to get loaded.

My index.html file loads correctly. My assets are all being loaded relative to my index.html file, which resides in the root directory.

The zip file I upload is structured like so:

[image]

Here are the errors I receive in the console when I try to load my canvas page in facebook; all 404s:

[image]

Here is the index.html file...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/flexboxgrid.min.css">
</head>
<body>    
    <div id="canvasContainer"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>    
    <script src="lib/pixi.min.js"></script>        
    <script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems like the resources simply aren't being uploaded.

I also noticed my index.html after looking at the dev tools networking tab is being loaded from `https://apps-<acc_key>.apps.fbsbx.com/bundle/<randomnumbers>/<more random numbers>/index.html?signed_request=.....` location.

However, my other resources don't have `'bundle/<randomnumbers>/<more random numbers>/'` apart of their address location. I attempted to load the resources up directly in the browser but I get a 403 Denied error. I even attempted to append the signed_reqeust token but no luck either; same 403 error.

Comment: share your index.html code so that we can inspect, also what you get when directly put a URL to browser address bar from your 404 errors console?

Comment: @SyedEkramuddinEmon Thanks for the response. I added some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the the problem is from `<base href="/" />` [tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base).

Web Hosting [Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/contenthosting/)

> It's very important that the generated index.html file is located at
>   the root of the zip file, as this is the only place we can launch the
>   content. **All other URLs need to be a relative path.**

---

**Correct** Relative urls

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>  
or
<link href="./styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Result url will be in the following format:

```
https://apps-<app id>.apps.fbsbx.com/bundle/<another id>/<another id>/styles.css
```

---

**Incorrect** Absolute urls

```
<link href="/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

https://apps-<app id>.apps.fbsbx.com/styles.css
```

---

And when you use `<base href="/" />` the HTML  element specifies the base URL to use for all relative URLs contained within a document. so basically you use absolute path, when you should rely on facebook web hosting to resolve the path

So change `/styles/main.css` to `styles/main.css` and remove `<base href="/" />`

Comment: You nailed it! Thanks a million! I don't even remember putting that base tag in there!